# Time and space complexity of a File Recursion algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, space-complexity

Is my time and space analysis correct for this algorithm?

```
def find_files(suffix, path):
if suffix == '':
    return []

# Base condition
if len(os.listdir(path)) == 0:
    return []

path_elements = os.listdir(path)
path_files = [file for file in path_elements if ('.' + suffix) in file]
path_folders = [folder for folder in path_elements if '.' not in folder]

for folder in path_folders:
    path_files.extend(find_files(suffix=suffix, path=path + '/' + folder))

return path_files

# Tests
path_base = os.getcwd() + '/testdir'
print(find_files(suffix='c', path=path_base))
```

## Explanation: File Recursion

**Requirement:**

The goal is to write code for finding all files under a directory (and all directories beneath it) that end with ".c"

**Summary:**

In order to implement this, I have used `find_files` function which will take `suffix` (file extension) and `path` (directory path where we need to search). In this function, I am recursively searching for a file with a given extension in a parent directory and all its sub-directories. I am storing all these files with a given suffix in a list and returning it.

**Time and Space Complexity:**

*Time Complexity:*

*os.listdir(path)* will list all the files and folders in a given path. Since it has to iterate over each item to provide a list, it takes linear time complexity. Let `e` be the length of the path_elements => `O(len(path_elements))`  => `O(e)`

```
path_elements = os.listdir(path)
```

2. Below line will find out all the files in a given path by checking if there is a `.c` in the file-name. If `s` is a length of the string (name of the file/folder), then it takes `O(s)` time to find out a file with the given extension. Therefore, for `f` number of files, it takes `O(f*s)` time. For practical purposes such as this, it is fair to assume that file-names are NOT infinitely long. Therefore, we can assume `s` as a constant => `O(f * 1)` => `O(f)`.

```
path_files = [file for file in path_elements if ('.' + suffix) in file]
```

3. Similarly,  traversing through `g` directories will take linear time =>  `O(g)`

```
path_folders = [folder for folder in path_elements if '.' not in folder]
```

The above 3 steps will take => `O(e + f + g)` => `O(e)`. Since, `e` (`len(path_elements)`) is a dominant term as it is a combination of `path_files` and `path_folders`

- For recursion, if `k` is the number of directories (`branches`) at each level in `depth` then the recursion will take `O(brancher^depth)` => `O(k^depth)`. But for every recursive call, above three steps are performed. Therefore, total time complexity is `O((k^depth) * e`

*Space Complexity:*

1. Input Space

   - suffix - `O(1)`
   - path - `O(1)`
   - path_elements + path_files + path_folders => `O(e + f + g)` => `O(e)`
2. Auxiliary Space

   Recursion uses something called as "call stack". When a function calls itself, that function goes on top of the stack.

   - In this algorithm, the recursive function is exhausted only if it has traversed every directory. In other words, when it has reached the `depth`. Therefore `O(depth)` space is required in the call stack.
3. Total Space Complexity => Input Space + Auxiliary Space => `O(e + depth)`

Comment: Why would you want to restrict folder names that contain `.`?

Comment: And you probably want to tighten up your condition a bit. You're looking for `('.' + suffix) in file`. That's going to catch ".com", ".cfg", "my.cool.file", and anything else that contains ".c" in it.

Comment: Good suggestion. In this case, let us assume that folder names do not have `.` and file names only have one `.`. I need your help to validate my time/space analysis. The code works fine for the given use case.

Bascially this is the folder structure:
```./testdir
./testdir/subdir1
./testdir/subdir1/a.c
./testdir/subdir1/a.h
./testdir/subdir2
./testdir/subdir2/.gitkeep
./testdir/subdir3
./testdir/subdir3/subsubdir1
./testdir/subdir3/subsubdir1/b.c
./testdir/subdir3/subsubdir1/b.h
./testdir/subdir4
./testdir/subdir4/.gitkeep
./testdir/t1.c
./testdir/t1.h```

Comment: Looks to me like the complexity is `O(path_elements)`, where `path_elements` is the total number of elements returned by all calls to `os.listdir`. There's a bit more work involved in getting 100 files from 10 different folders rather than from just two folders, but it varies by a constant. The *actual* time it takes will be somewhat different, though.

Comment: How about the complexity of recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the complexity is O(path_elements), where `path_elements` is the total number of files and folders returned by all calls to `os.listdir()`. Consider a folder that has four files in a single directory:

```
folder
  zip.c
  foo.c
  bar.c
  bas.c
```

So your function calls `os.listdir()`, which returns four files. So `n = 4`. The code then iterates over the list to find folders, of which it finds none, and again to pick out the .c files, which it adds to the list.

The complexity here is O(n) to call `os.listdir()`, O(n) to search for folders, and O(n) to pick out the .c files and add them to the list. Altogether O(3*n), which is O(n).

Now consider this directory tree:

```
folder
  sub1
    zip.c
    foo.c
  sub2
    bar.c
    bas.c
```

So the first call to `find_files` calls `os.listdir(folder)`, which returns two folders. Each folder makes a recursive call to `find_files`. Altogether there are three calls to `os.listdir()`, and each one returns two files, so the total number of items returned by `os.listdir()` is 6.

Now imagine you had:

```
folder
  sub0
    sub1
      sub2
        sub3
          ...
            sub30
              file1.c
```

The complexity here is still O(n). In this case, n is 31.

The point I'm trying to make here is that you look at each item returned from `os.listdir()` a constant number of times. Thus, O(n).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. It makes sense now.